# How should dependancy property values be validated on WPF custom controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am fairly new to professional development, working in a team that develops custom controls in WPF for use in applications. We recently had a bug report that on our Numeric Up Down the value can briefly exceed the maximum before it is validated and set to the maximum. We use CoerceCallbacks as validation for the values, and as we have found out, this passes the coerced value to the control but the actual underlying data is not changed. This meant that the app developers developed their own NumericUpDown where the validation used a similar method to a CoercedCallBack, but they performed the validation in the SetValue for the dependency property, using a custom SetValue method.

We are basically wondering if there is stronger validation that can be performed, or if CoerceCallBacks are correct. The method of validating in the SetValue for the property does not seem like a good solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "this passes the coerced value to the control but the actual underlying data is not changed": Can you point to the underlying data in some example code? Do you mean the viewmodel property value?

Comment: Validating in the property setter is definitely wrong, because it may not even be called. WPF may bypass the setter and call SetValue directly, e.g. when the property is set by a Binding.

Comment: Hi Ed, I' may be able to cobble some code together at some point tomorrow. essentially, the app devs were creating a Model class, which had a Max, Min and Value. The ViewModel had Max, MIn and Value properties, in the accessories they were accessing the properties on a Model instance, and the View was binding Max, Min and Value of the control to the ViewModel properties.

Comment: @TomPeters Is one of those the one you call "underlying value"?

Comment: I think the app devs are using the Model instance of the value eg: Model mod = new Model(). The the ViewModel property is accessing mod.Value

Comment: @TomPeters It sounds like you're hinting that "underlying value" means the value that's bound to the control property.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yeah I think so, sorry I am not being more explicit, I don't work on apps so my MVVM knowledge is limited